# Django Rest Framework, passing a parameter with url to ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I want to pass a parameter in the url and use it to filter the objects.
My view so far looks like this.

```
class RecipeIngredientViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = RecipeIngredient.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeIngredientSerializer
```

I would like to get all the ingredients related to one recipe. Like this:

```
queryset = RecipeIngredient.objects.filter(recipe_id=id)
```

When I hardcode `recipe_id=1` it's working.
 Thats the line in url:

```
router.register(r'recipe/', views.RecipeIngredientViewSet)
```

Tried different approaches and failed so far. I'll be glad for any help.

Comment: Use [**django-filter**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.html) package, which might be useful in your context

Comment: For passing a parameter with URL to ModelViewSet, please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65378199/pass-a-custom-param-in-url-with-a-modelviewset)