# Pass a custom param in URL with a ModelViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

What's the best way of passing a **param** using a `ModelViewSet`? Forexample achieving something like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/financing-settings/template/?param=block
```

Below is the approach I was using but found out I have set the param in the body section, but it's not what I want :

```
class TemplateView(ModelViewSet):
    """ViewSet for Saving Block/ Step template."""

   
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

        """Get list of Block/Steps with is_process_template is equal to True."""
        param = request.data['param']

        if param == "block":
            _block = Block.objects.filter(is_process_template=True).values()
            return JsonResponse({"data": list(_block)}, safe=False, status=200)

        elif param == "step":
            _step = Step.objects.filter(is_process_template=True).values()
            return JsonResponse({"data": list(_step)}, safe=False, status=200)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Comment: Why is your approach not what you want? The param is not in the request body it is in `request.GET`, DRF adds the `request.data` dict which is a merge of all GET/POST/FILES data from the request afaik

Comment: @IainShelvington, my apporoach is not what I want leading to a challenge am facing now, though please shed more light on what you've said

Comment: What challenge? Reading the param from request.GET is pretty much the way to read query parameters

Comment: @IainShelvington, I have seen it it, it returns a QueryDict:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 param = request.GET.get('param')
```

or for a post request

```
 param = request.POST.get('param')
```

Answer (score 0):

param = request.query_params.get('param')

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).